# What is Spree::Gateway::Paypal proper integration?

Tags: spree

I see login, password, signature, currency code, and server.

What are each of these supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

The Spree PayPal gateway uses ActiveMerchant under the covers.  The login, password, and signature should all come from API tokens for your PayPal account.  This answer contains more detail:

[activemerchant paypal gateway configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453597/activemerchant-paypal-gateway-configuration)

Currency Code is the the three letter ISO code for the currency you're using (for example, 'USD' for US Dollars).

Server will also come from paypal and generally be api.sandbox.paypal.com or api.paypal.com depending on whether you are operating in the sandbox or production environments.

Answer (score 0):

From scratch testing

First you have to go to [Paypal developer's website](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) and create and account

Then generate sandbox user type `business` then click on `Profile` option and then click on `API Credentials` tab you will finally the required data such login/username, password/password, signature/signature

[image]